# Absolute convergence of $\sum a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

I would ask a help for the following problem If someone could tell me what criteria or applies so I would appreciate. Show that if $ \sum \limits^{\infty }_{n=1}a_n $ is absolutely convergent, then $ \sum \limits^{\infty }_{n=1}(a_n)^{2} $  is convergent and Give an example to show that the converse is false

Comment: Please edit your post to have $a_n$ rather than $an.$

Comment: You didn't finish your statement. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2$ is what?

Comment: What did you try so far? Both statements are very trivial to show. The counterexapmle, for example, can be probably the most famous non-convergent series you can think of...

Comment: @5xum, please let's be civil.  Your comments are, literally, trivializing OP's questions.

Comment: $$\sum\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$ would be a counter example.

Comment: I tried to edit the title because the way it is spelled reads like some new flavor of vodka: but the system said there is already a question titled "Absolute convergence".  So I guess it stands as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  If $\sum|a_n|$ converges, then $a_n^2 \leqslant |a_n| < 1$ for $n$ sufficiently large.